# Why do I still have mach-o linker errors in my iOS project even after removing the files that caused them?

Tags: iphone, linker, asihttprequest, mach-o

These are the errors:

```
Ld /Users/gearhead2727/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TR-bwdsurqqtlxmnhdpvfqmdqftqsun/Build/Intermediates/TR.build/Debug-iphoneos/TR.build/Objects-normal/armv6/TR normal armv6
    cd /Users/gearhead2727/Dropbox/TR
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0.1
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/gearhead2727/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TR-bwdsurqqtlxmnhdpvfqmdqftqsun/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos "-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/usr/lib" -F/Users/gearhead2727/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TR-bwdsurqqtlxmnhdpvfqmdqftqsun/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/gearhead2727/Dropbox/TR/../../Downloads -filelist /Users/gearhead2727/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TR-bwdsurqqtlxmnhdpvfqmdqftqsun/Build/Intermediates/TR.build/Debug-iphoneos/TR.build/Objects-normal/armv6/TR.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -miphoneos-version-min=4.0.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AddressBookUI -lz.1.1.3 -lsqlite3.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework AddressBook -framework GameKit -framework AVFoundation -framework MessageUI -lxml2 -framework StoreKit -o /Users/gearhead2727/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TR-bwdsurqqtlxmnhdpvfqmdqftqsun/Build/Intermediates/TR.build/Debug-iphoneos/TR.build/Objects-normal/armv6/TR

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_class_addMethod", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TRAppDelegate in TRAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TRAppDelegate in TRAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TRViewController in TRViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TRViewController in TRViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBet in SBet.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBet in SBet.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RaceView in RaceView.o
      ...
  "_method_getTypeEncoding", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "___objc_personality_v0", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "_ceil", referenced from:
      _EstimateBas64EncodedDataSize in Base64Transcoder.o
      -[FBDialog sizeToFitOrientation:] in FBDialog.o
      -[FBDialog drawRect:] in FBDialog.o
  "_sel_registerName", referenced from:
      -[NSObject(WeakLinking) findSelectorForProperty:named:forReading:] in NSObject+WeakLinking.o
  "_class_getInstanceMethod", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "_floor", referenced from:
      -[FBDialog sizeToFitOrientation:] in FBDialog.o
      -[FBDialog show] in FBDialog.o
  "_CC_MD5", referenced from:
      -[FBRequest md5HexDigest:] in FBRequest.o
  "_objc_getProperty", referenced from:
      -[SHKOAuthSharer signatureProvider] in SHKOAuthSharer.o
      -[SHKOAuthSharer accessToken] in SHKOAuthSharer.o
      -[SHKOAuthSharer requestToken] in SHKOAuthSharer.o
      -[SHKOAuthSharer consumer] in SHKOAuthSharer.o
      -[SHKSharer request] in SHKSharer.o
      -[SHKSharer pendingForm] in SHKSharer.o
      -[SHKSharer item] in SHKSharer.o
      ...
  "_objc_setProperty", referenced from:
      -[TRAppDelegate setWindow:] in TRAppDelegate.o
      -[TRAppDelegate setViewController:] in TRAppDelegate.o
      -[TRViewController setGameCenterManager:] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController setCurrentLeaderboard:] in TRViewController.o
      -[FacebookAgent setUserInfo:] in FacebookAgent.o
      -[FacebookAgent setPermissionStatus:] in FacebookAgent.o
      -[FacebookAgent setUploadImageAlbum:] in FacebookAgent.o
      ...
  "_objc_enumerationMutation", referenced from:
      -[SHK showViewController:] in SHK.o
      +[SHK favoriteSharersForType:] in SHK.o
      +[SHK logoutOfAll] in SHK.o
      +[SHK flushOfflineQueue] in SHK.o
      +[SHKOAuthSharer logout] in SHKOAuthSharer.o
      -[SHKSharer isAuthorized] in SHKSharer.o
      -[SHKSharer authorizationFormSave:] in SHKSharer.o
      ...
  "_objc_sync_enter", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "_class_replaceMethod", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "_CCHmac", referenced from:
      -[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider signClearText:withSecret:] in OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider.o
  "_property_getAttributes", referenced from:
      -[NSObject(WeakLinking) findSelectorForProperty:named:forReading:] in NSObject+WeakLinking.o
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TRAppDelegate in TRAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TRAppDelegate in TRAppDelegate.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TRViewController in TRViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TRViewController in TRViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBet in SBet.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBet in SBet.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RaceView in RaceView.o
      ...
  "_method_getImplementation", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "_class_getProperty", referenced from:
      -[NSObject(WeakLinking) findSelectorForPropertyNamed:forReading:] in NSObject+WeakLinking.o
  "_round", referenced from:
      +[SHKActivityIndicator currentIndicator] in SHKActivityIndicator.o
      -[SHKActivityIndicator setCenterMessage:] in SHKActivityIndicator.o
      -[SHKActivityIndicator showSpinner] in SHKActivityIndicator.o
      -[SHKFormFieldCell layoutSubviews] in SHKFormFieldCell.o
  "_objc_sync_exit", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "__Unwind_SjLj_Unregister", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      -[TRAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in TRAppDelegate.o
      -[TRAppDelegate dealloc] in TRAppDelegate.o
      -[TRViewController madeTurtle] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController soundButtonPress:] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController launchTurtleMaker:] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController pressRestart:] in TRViewController.o
      ...
  "_method_exchangeImplementations", referenced from:
      _SHKSwizzle in SHK.o
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[TRAppDelegate dealloc] in TRAppDelegate.o
      -[TRViewController dealloc] in TRViewController.o
      -[TRViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in TRViewController.o
      -[SBet initWithFrame:] in SBet.o
      -[SBet dealloc] in SBet.o
      -[LoadedTurtleView viewDidLoad] in LoadedTurtleView.o
      -[FacebookAgent initWithApiKey:ApiSecret:ApiProxy:] in FacebookAgent.o
      ...
  "__Unwind_SjLj_Resume", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "__Unwind_SjLj_Register", referenced from:
      +[FBTranslationsLoader sharedInstance] in FBTranslationsLoader.o
  "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      -[RaceView useSpeedTurt] in RaceView.o
      -[RaceView beginRace] in RaceView.o
      -[RaceView viewDidLoad] in RaceView.o
      -[RaceView moveTurtles] in RaceView.o
      -[TurtleMakerController addImage:addImage:addImage:addImage:] in TurtleMakerController.o
      -[UserRaceView viewDidLoad] in UserRaceView.o
      -[UserRaceView uMoveButton:] in UserRaceView.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I got them when I added ASIHTTPREQUEST, and I removed ASIHTTPREQUEST and the errors stayed. Before I added ASITHTTPREQUEST there were no errors so please help me get rid of the errors.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your build?

Comment: It didn't rid the errors even though it said clean successful.., thanks for the input though

Comment: In my experience, sometimes deleting the build folder does a little more than cleaning does. Also, if you're using Xcode 4, it apparently has some kind of caching built in, so also restart Xcode for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Quit xcode
2. rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
3. rm -rf <project-dir>/build

It also looks like you're probably missing one of the fundamental base libraries going by the errors. Try reverting your .xcodeproj back to a version prior to adding asihttprequest?